# Counting Parse.com Data - Java

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am pulling code from my Parse.com database and storing it into an ArrayList. I am then converting the ArrayList into a String array so I can put it into a ListView. Everything works good and dandy, with one exception. Let me show you.

Here is how I am pulling code from my Parse.com database.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("myClassName");

query.whereEqualTo("Parse.com Column", /**int inside the column*/ );
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            //My Code Here
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The code above would search though each column in Parse.com and look for the int you define in the column. Once the object is found, You can pull from that object.

Now here is what I wrote with that code:

```
public void getData() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Merchandize");

    query.whereEqualTo("simpleID", simpleID);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    items.add(list.get(i).getString("item"));
                    Log.i("KOTB", list.get(i).getString("item"));

                    itemDesc.add(list.get(i).getString("description"));
                    simpleID++;
                    if (simpleID <= 13) {

                        Log.i("KOTB", "re-running getData()");
                        getData();
                    } else  if (simpleID > 14){
                        arrayAdapterMethod();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void arrayAdapterMethod() {
    Log.i("KOTB", "==arrayAdapterMethod()==");
    Log.i("KOTB","Converting");
    String array[] = new String[items.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++) {
        array[j] = items.get(j);
        Log.e("KOTB", array[j]);
    }

    for (String k: array) {
        Log.w("KOTB [NOTE]", k);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

It is searching though the Parse.com data in the column called simpleID and once it finds the int it is searching for inside the simpleID it runs code.
Just incase you would like to take a look at my Parse.com table, here you go:

http://gyazo.com/62d4b37f531c54bf65089958e5af11fc

Now here is my problem. my **if statments** inside **void done < getData** I have predefined numbers.

```
                        if (simpleID <= 13) {

                        Log.i("KOTB", "re-running getData()");
                        getData();
                    } else  if (simpleID > 14){
                        arrayAdapterMethod();
                    }
```

If I where to add an item in my Parse.com database it would not read that in my code, because of the hardcoded numbers.

> **How can I count how many SimpleIDs I have, and save them into an int?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how your code is reading.

get all simpleID's that match int simpleID

```
query.whereEqualTo("simpleID", simpleID);
```

I am going to assume that you have simpleID defined as `int simpleID = 0;`

The list returned here will be all rows where "simpleID" is equal to your `this.simpleID`

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                items.add(list.get(i).getString("item"));
                Log.i("KOTB", list.get(i).getString("item"));

                itemDesc.add(list.get(i).getString("description"));
                simpleID++;
```

If simpleID is less than your ?max? simpleID then run getData again with a new simpleID

```
                if (simpleID <= 13) {

                    Log.i("KOTB", "re-running getData()");
                    getData();
                } else  if (simpleID > 14){
                    arrayAdapterMethod();
                }

            }
        }
    }
});
```

It seems as if you are iterating through all the items in your table and putting them into an array of strings. Even if you set your `this.simpleID` to an initialized value you are still getting all rows of that table from that simpleID value and above. My suggestion is to use a `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("simpleId", simpleID)` query. The result from this query would allow you to remove the simpleId increment and just have a single list to iterate over.
Something like this would do I think.

```
public void getData() {
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Merchandize");

query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("simpleID", simpleID);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                items.add(list.get(i).getString("item"));
                Log.i("KOTB", list.get(i).getString("item"));

                itemDesc.add(list.get(i).getString("description"));
            }
            arrayAdapterMethod();
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```